# How to split apart the word order in English?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I've got the following sentence:

'**Every now and then a ray of moonlight through the branches above lit a spot of silver blue blood on the fallen leaves**.'

It's originally from the Harry Potter book.

Here we have the part '**through the branches above**' that cracked up the SVO order.

I don't know how to explain, but it seems quite strange.
If I say '**a ray of moonlight shining through the branches above lit a spot of blood**', it's fine

but if I don't have an adjective clause it looks weird.

It seems more natural to say 'a ray of moonlight lit a spot of silver blue blood through the branches above'

Simplifying, we could say '**A ray lit a spot through the branches**', not '**a ray through the branches lit a spot**' A Method comes after.

Here is the question: Could I write sentences such as the last one and what's a grammatically correct way to do it?

Update:
I've found an answer.

> "I ate steak in pepper sauce"

Ordinary people think that ''in pepper sauce'' is adjectival, whereas I ate steak while sitting in pepper sauce. I couldn't see how ''through the branches'' could modify 'a ray' without adding one more word

> ''a ray **shining** through the branches lit a spot''

Without 'shining' there was just one possibility for me, which is to light something through branches.

however, the original Rowling's sentence could be interpreted in **both** ways.
But it is archaic to put an adverb before the verb it modifies. (And this is why I asked the question. It felt weird in terms of an adverbial interpretation)

So...an adverbial version:

> Every now and then a ray of moonlight faintly lit a spot of silver blue blood on the fallen leaves.

an adjectival version:

> 'Every now and then a ray of moonlight shining through the branches above lit a spot of silver blue blood on the fallen leaves.'

Comment: Rowling is a billionaire, not a stylist.

Comment: @Robusto: Have you tried writing a seven-volume series of novels without a single vaguely grammatically questionable sentence? People nitpick on Rowling way too much (probably because she is a billionaire).

Comment: @Robusto So? Being either of those things has nothing to do with whether you can write entertaining prose. In fact I'd argue the best prose ignores style guidelines frequently. Otherwise, novels would be awfully boring. But I suppose some people are obsessed with following rules, even when they don't actually exist...

Comment: @PeterShor: That is not the issue, and you know it. Personally, I found her unreadable—and I really, really tried to read her because my son was so into the series. I don't begrudge her her success, but apparently for all her wealth none of it went into an editor who would stand up to her excesses. For fantasy, give me Ursula K. LeGuin *any* day.

Comment: @only_pro: Yeah, yeah, and money = talent in our world. I remain unimpressed, but you enjoy what you enjoy and I'll enjoy something else.

Comment: @Robusto I'm not defending Rowling. Just pointing out that your comment is ludicrous and irrelevant to the situation. Millions of people love her work. There's clearly something about the writing that works for many people. It's okay if you don't like it, but don't try and posit that it's bad because it doesn't follow style guidelines to a T. *Most* popular novels do not. You're not making any kind of valid or relevant argument here...

Comment: @only_pro: You're making the argument I said you were making. I suggest we end it there, because comments aren't for extended discussion.

Comment: @Robusto Haha. You're a funny one.. *You* said money = talent in our world. I did not. I have not claimed Rowling is talented or a good writer (which is purely subjective). I was just pointing out that your original comment is *ludicrous*, and it remains so. Being a "stylist" (as you put it), has *absolutely nothing* to do with whether you're a good writer.

Comment: @only_pro: So ... I wonder why you're so butt-hurt about this. "Millions of people love her work" is the argument I was talking about. Think what you like, I really don't care. I said what I meant to say, not something close to it—unlike Rowling.

Comment: @Robusto No, no... *I'm* wondering why *you're* so butt-hurt about this. You posted the original comment! I was simply clarifying, for others' sake, that your comment is irrelevant and makes no sense. Accuracy is important on this site. If you'd like to explain why you think being a stylist is important for being a good writer, perhaps there's a question for that on here.

Comment: Guys, your argument is fine, but how about the topic?

Comment: @ThroughTheWonders Comments aren't for answering questions!

Comment: Ahem. In the spirit of staying on-topic: first off, "a ray through the branches lit a spot" is fine. It's not the usual order but you can use it under poetic license any day. Secondly and more importantly: I believe you've simplified the example to an extent where it has become something else entirely. In the original phrase, "through the branches" modifies *ray*. A ray of light through the branches. That's a single unit. And then that unit does something. In the usual order. You are trying to reduce it to a construction where "through the branches" modifies *lit*. And so you run into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you think that Rowling has made some error. The formulation is just like: " A sip of tea from a porcelain cup refreshes the spirits."
 The phrase "through the branches" is adjectival, distinguishing the ray of moonlight from other rays of moonlight that have not passed through branches. 
Whether other less wealthy writers would have chosen those words has no bearing on whether the rules of grammar, such as they are, have been broken.

Answer (score 2):

Rowling's version is fine grammatically. Prepositional phrases can serve as [adjective phrases](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/prepphrases/) as well as adverb phrases, and prepositional phrases modifying verbs can appear before the verb.

You are right that [*through*, leading a prepositional phrase, tends to follow a verb](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/through_1?q=through), whether that would be *lit* or your hypothetical gerundive *shining*.

However, *through*, like other prepositional phrases, can also follow a noun. In this case, *through* may modify *moonlight* directly. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through#examples) features a pair of examples:

> a highway through the forest
>
> a road through the desert

Here's an example from the 2016 novel *[Promised to the Crown](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Promised_to_the_Crown/94xKCgAAQBAJ?hl=en)*, where "light" is modified by *through her cell window* without a clear verb correspondent:

> Seeing the dawn light through her cell window proved a disappointment that morning and many afterward.

In a more scientific context, here's [a passage](https://archive.org/stream/Astronomy_March_2015-03/Astronomy_March_2015-03_djvu.txt) about light transmitted through a vacuum without using a verb like "transmitted":

> The speed of light through a vacuum is exactly 299,792,458 meters per second, or 670,616,629 mph

In these examples, it is clear that the first noun is somehow *moving* or *being transmitted* **through** the preposition's object. No verb and no rearrangement of the syntax to follow a verb is necessary.

---

Even if we wanted to consider "through" as an adverbial phrase modifying the verb "lit," moving the phrase "through" to precede the verb occasionally happens in literary use. Samuel Taylor Coleridge affects a lyrical style in *[Rime of the Ancient Mariner](https://books.google.com/books?id=_dx1AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT293&lpg=PT293&dq=Every%20tongue%20through%27%20utter%20drouth%20Was%20wither%27d%20at%20the%20root.&source=bl&ots=T1Lo9wxa8W&sig=ACfU3U3O6hGgyXBdBYSNx7DlB-oXmEdF4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP8oe2vungAhWkUt8KHcRIB0sQ6AEwEXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Every%20tongue%20through%27%20utter%20drouth%20Was%20wither%27d%20at%20the%20root.&f=false)* to do just that:

> And every tongue thro' utter drouth / Was wither'd at the root

Or John Milton in *[Samson Agonistes](https://books.google.com/books?id=GjFdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=If%20he%20through%20frailty%20err&source=bl&ots=aKv2Gok74P&sig=ACfU3U2mmuEWGHi3jRTFut6XuchYR17uBw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij6JaxxOngAhVOMd8KHWHYDUEQ6AEwBnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=If%20he%20through%20frailty%20err&f=false)*:

> If he through frailty err

The expressions sound distinct, and we could discuss further whether Rowling's *style* entirely works here (she's no poet), but the usage is fine grammatically.

Comment: So...If we take the phrase 'Megan put her bird in its cage.' and turn it into 'Megan in its cage put her bird.' it is still correct even after the transformation?

Comment: No, it's incorrect, but the primary issue is the use of a pronoun before the thing it refers to.

Comment: Otherwise, the placement is grammatically correct, if stylistically distinct and not common in styles of writing that privilege clarity.

Comment: Does treating the prepositional phrase as the adjectival phrase really works?

It's really important because it changes the meaning.

Comment: It works because this is one of the things prepositional phrases commonly do, as "a ray of moonlight through the branches above" forms a larger noun phrase, and "speed of light through a vacuum" forms a larger noun phrase.

Comment: Could we consider the prepositional phrase from our original sentence also as a verb-modifier? Or if so, our phrase have to follow the verb only?

Answer (score 0):

The prepositional phrase is adverbial, and it is right where it belongs. Compare:

> Every now and then a ray of moonlight faintly lit a spot of silver 
>       blue blood on the fallen leaves.

with

> Every now and then a ray of moonlight through the branches above lit a spot of silver
>       blue blood on the fallen leaves.
>   The grammar is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the delete thing works. My deleted comment appears on my screen, maybe not on others'.  But since someone upvoted my answer, I guess I should make it available.  I would amend it to say that treating the prepositional phrase as adjectival works, too.

Comment: So...Faintly is an adverb. We could treat our phrase as an adverb, right?
'a ray of moonlight through the branches above lit a spot'
How did ray light a spot?
'Through the branches above.' or 'faintly'

But it means that our phrase describes the verb lit. Not a noun 'ray'! That's what I was talking about. Adverbs cannot modify nouns.

Comment: @ThroughTheWonders - Yes, it can be an adjectival phrase, too, modifying "ray," as I said in my comment appearing immediately above yours.

Comment: That's the wrong place for an adverbial prepositional phrase (although a perfectly fine place for a solitary adverb). Compare **The blue car down the street drove* and *The house down the street is blue*. The first *down the street* is adverbial, and unconventionally positioned (although it's acceptable for poetry), while the second is adjectival and positioned correctly.

Comment: @PeterShor I believe you are talking style, not grammar.  Some style rules are very powerful with respect to idiomatic speaking and writing, but the placement of adverbial phrases has been grammatically optional at least since lilacs last in the dooryard bloomed. But hark!  What light through yon window breaks?

Comment: Shakespeare used different grammar than we do. And Walt Whitman was writing poetry (which I said this placement was acceptable for).

Comment: And Rowling is writing literary prose, not an academic study. She may as much as any other author move the pieces around the board. (I would have defended Shakespeare on poetic grounds, too.  Did people really talk like that back then?)

Comment: @remarki: Grammar aside, a prepositional phrase between the subject and the verb has a very strong tendency to be perceived as adjectival. Consider: *Our neighbors down the street drove an antique car.* And that's true of Rowling's sentence—I think it has to be adjectival.

Comment: @PeterShor I agree with that. Your example shows the default interpretation where context does not make clear what is meant. But there is a difference between your example and Rowling's. In your case, the choice of adjectival vs. adverbial affects the meaning of the sentence.  In Rowling's case, we don't really care whether the ray is coming through the leaves or the spot is being lit through the leaves. That gives the author some flexibility not present in your example.

Comment: Guys, can you imagine my problem? "I ate steak in pepper sauce"
Ordinary people think that ''in pepper sauce'' is adjectival, whereas I ate steak while sitting in pepper sauce. I couldn't see how ''through the branches'' could modify 'a ray'. It would have been way too easy to see if it contained SHINING ''a ray shining through the branches lit a spot'

It is also possible to interpret the original sentence as adverbial! I've asked. But it is archaic to put an adverb before the verb it modifies

Comment: @ThroughTheWonders -  I quickly dashed off a response, but I had hardly finished when I reluctantly changed my mind.

Comment: @remarkl Are you a native English speaker? At least I wasn't being alone thinking about adverbial interpretation (Now I know that It could be working as well, though in an archaic way)

Comment: @ThroughTheWonders No, I'm from New York.  Speaking of which, I just read a review in The New Yorker, which quoted a passage about "the light from the parking lot [illuminating]" something or other.  There, the PP is almost certainly adjectival.  Here. nothing depends on the label attached to the PP. The meaning of the sentence is unchanged by the a decision regarding the type of PP in play. It's like that disputed land on the Russian-Polish border that finally ended up in Polish hands to the delight of the natives, who would no longer have to endure those awful Russian winters.